# Send a POST request only through WiFi interface

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection, android-wifi

I have a chip with a WiFi module on it, which acts as an access point. What I'm trying to do is connect to the AP (which has no Internet access), send a POST request to a local address (http://192.168.4.1/address) and receive a response from the chip. I am writing an Android application, which is supposed to do that (and it does most of the time).

The problem is, I have a test device, which has this optimizing feature and checks if the WiFi network you're connected to has Internet access and if not, it uses mobile data automatically. I don't want that so I would want to either "force" the application to send it through the WiFi interface or find a workaround.

I use `HttpURLConnection` at the moment and it works like a charm if I turn off my mobile data. Otherwise it just waits and at the end triggers the timeout.

I have searched a lot about this issue and so far I have found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android 5 (API 21), you can force connections to use the WiFi even if it's not the default network.

One solution is to find the corresponding network, for example with [`ConnectivityManager.getAllNetworks()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworks()) and [`ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo(android.net.Network)):

Once you have the [`Network`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network), you can either :

- Open a connection on this network using [`Network.openConnection()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#openConnection(java.net.URL)).
- Bind the application to the network with [`ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#setProcessDefaultNetwork(android.net.Network)) or [`ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#bindProcessToNetwork(android.net.Network)) (API 23+)

See [Connecting your App to a Wi-Fi Device](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/connecting-your-app-to-wi-fi-device.html) (especially *Routing network requests*) for more details.

Comment: Hi @bwt, thanks for your answer! It helped! But the thing I get from getAllNetworks() is just a 3-digit number (First I got 267, then 270, then when I turned my Mobile data on, i got 2 numbers - 272, 273). Is there a way to identify which is which? Or should I just check which one has an Internet connection and connect to the other?

Comment: `getNetworkInfo()`  takes a `Network` and give a `NetworkInfo` containing more info like the network type

Comment: Thank you! I will test it next week.